# table-scroll.min.js and table-scroll.js files are missing from my Visual Studio 2019 MVC project

Tags: file, model-view-controller

table-scroll.min.js and table-scroll.js files are missing from my Visual Studio 2019 MVC project.
I have no Idea where they came from, but I have added NuGet packages. Also, my layout page and styles of the project (web application) are not functioning as expected. As a result, the front end of the application is not displaying as expected.
I have searched online, but could not come up with a thing that is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I made a backup to my project previously, so I took the missing files from there, and added them to my current project. That solved the problem, and the web application displays as
expected.

I lost the files when I was using a software version control, the mistake has to do
with checking some files with the project. The needed files where not added to the checked in software.